# Is Connection.BeginTransaction() different from SQL begin transaction?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Today someone said C# `connection.BeginTransaction()` is different from T-SQL's `begin transaction`, so I tested it and the result seemed to be true.

C# code using `connection.BeginTransaction()`:

```
using (var connection = Connection)
{
    connection.Open();
    var cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "create table #TransactionTest ([ID] int);";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into #TransactionTest ([ID]) values (1);";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into #TransactionTest ([ID]) values (1);";
        cmd.Transaction = transaction;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        transaction.Rollback();
    }

    cmd.CommandText = "select count(1) from #TransactionTest";
    var count = cmd.ExecuteScalar(); //result : 0 count
}
```

C# code using T-SQL `Begin Transaction`:

```
using (var connection = Connection)
{
    connection.Open();
    var cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "create table #TransactionTest ([ID] int);";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into #TransactionTest ([ID]) values (1);";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    cmd.CommandText = "begin transaction;";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into #TransactionTest ([ID]) values (1);";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.CommandText = "rollback;";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    cmd.CommandText = "select count(1) from #TransactionTest";
    var count = cmd.ExecuteScalar(); //result : 0 count
}
```

In my mind this logic is equivalent to the following SQL:

```
create table #TransactionTest ([ID] int, [Value] varchar(32));

begin transaction;
    insert into #TransactionTest ([ID], [Value]) 
    values (1, 'ABC');

    rollback transaction ;

    insert into #TransactionTest ([ID]) 
    values (1); 

    select * from #TransactionTest;
```

I found no begin transaction action using SQL Server Profiler tuning with C# `connection.BeginTransaction`

[image: 20190317231252-image.png]

but found C# sql BeginTransaction
[image: 20190318002252-image.png]

**Question:**

Is it real, or is it just hidden from the database?

Comment: The default configuration for SQL Profiler doesn't show transactions.  I'd look at that.

Comment: I choose the SQL Profiler tunning template @Stephen Wrighton  , i am searching google for transation profiler.

Comment: you'll need to check "show all events" and create a new profile template. 
 here's  a link: https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/where-is-transaction-events-in-sql-server-profiler

Comment: Just add the Transaction events directly to the trace, under the Transaction group in Profiler. Note that client APIs can manage transactions directly over the TDS protocol so there isn't a T-SQL statement executed.

Comment: thanks  @Stephen Wrighton  you can answer below, it's answer

Comment: Thank you. I see ,C# connection.BeginTransaction() is calling DB TM BeginTransaction directly instead of calling sqll BeginTransaction -> call TM BeginTransaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are significant differences because of the way transactions are implemented in .NET, although in many cases (like in your example) they appear to act the same.

- Transactions in SQL Server will auto-promote on an as-needed basis. 
  ADO.NET transactions will not.
- ADO.NET will not allow parallel
  transactions, even if multiple result sets are enabled.
- ADO.NET
  transactions are bound to the Connection object, which is evident in
  the code but confuses folks easily:

```
var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction()
```

- Why is it confusing?  Because Command objects are **also** bound to the Connection, but a transaction in the Connection doesn't equate to a transaction in its Command objects.

  - Example: Take your Connection that has a transaction started, create a new Command with it and try to execute.  It will fail unless you explicitly provide the transaction to the new Command object.

As a matter of best practices, I have found the following to be true:

- Stored procedures are the best way to avoid issues when transactions are necessary
- Having DDL (even for temp tables) in a transaction should be avoided.  SQL Server will allow it, but other databases like Oracle will not.

You can read lots more about it in the MS documentation [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/transactions-and-concurrency)